# How to specify `container` section only for linux runner in github actions

Tags: github-actions

I need to specify container parameters in the case of linux, but my job needs to be run also in windows, this is my yaml file

```
name: My Build
on:
  push
jobs:
  job1:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: ["windows-latest", "ubuntu-latest"]
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os}}
    container:
      image: catthehacker/ubuntu:runner-latest
      options: --privileged      
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo "${{ matrix.os }}"
```

It runs in linux but fails in windows with the message `Error: Container operations are only supported on Linux runners`

I have not found any conditional expression to ignore the `container` section in windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to configure with matrix strategy. So you have to split this into separate jobs like

```
name: My Build
on:
  push
jobs:
  jobLinux:
    runs-on: "ubuntu-latest"
    container:
      image: catthehacker/ubuntu:runner-latest
      options: --privileged      
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo "${{ runner.os }}"

  jobWindows:
    needs: []
    runs-on: "windows-latest"   
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo "${{ runner.os }}"
```

And to avoid repeating steps in jobs you should use [composite action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action) or [reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows).